# React Native Multiple Fetch Returns Wrong Values

Tags: react-native, components, fetch

I'm trying to get fetches from multiple different sources. 
The URL (for example 'this.country["A"] + this.props.productLink') is json data for each country. 
So what I'm expecting is to get corresponding returns for each country. 
However, when I print the result, it misses some countries' values but instead prints other countury's values like [COUNTRY3,COUNTRY3,COUNTRY4,COUNTRY5,COUNTRY6,COUNTRY7,COUNTRY8,COUNTRY9,COUNTRY3,COUNTRY3].
The length of result array is 10 which is as expected though. I used promises.all to get order preservation. I wonder why it happens.

Under componentDidMount():

```
fetchData()
{
    Promise.all([axios.get(this.country["A"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["B"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["C"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["D"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["E"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["F"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["G"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["H"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["I"] + this.props.productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["J"] + this.props.productLink)])
    .then(([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5, res6, res7, res8, res9, res10]) => { 
        return Promise.all([res1.data, res2.data, res3.data, res4.data, res5.data, res6.data, res7.data, res8.data, res9.data, res10.data]) 
    })
    .then(([res1, res2, res3, res4, res5, res6, res7, res8, res9, res10]) => {
        const rawLoaded = [res1[this.priceSelector],res2[this.priceSelector],res3[this.priceSelector],res4[this.priceSelector],res5[this.priceSelector],
                res6[this.priceSelector],res7[this.priceSelector],res8[this.priceSelector],res9[this.priceSelector],res10[this.priceSelector]]
        console.log(rawLoaded)
        if (rawLoaded.length == 10)
            this.setState({isloading:true, rawPrice:rawLoaded})
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be happening because of how you're handling your data. First of all, you don't need to manually create a new array in both `.then()` callbacks, a better practice would be to call `.map()` on the existing arrays. You also don't need to call `Promise.all()` after you received the responses from `axios` as none of what you're passing in is a `Promise`. Give the following implementation a shot.

```js
function fetchData() {
    const { productLink } = this.props;

    Promise.all([
        axios.get(this.country["A"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["B"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["C"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["D"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["E"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["F"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["G"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["H"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["I"] + productLink),
        axios.get(this.country["J"] + productLink)
    ])
    .then(results => {
        const resultData = results.map(res => res.data);
        const rawLoaded = resultData.map(data => data[this.priceSelector]);

        if (rawLoaded.length != 10) {
            console.warn('Unexpected output');
            return;
        }

        this.setState({ 
            isLoading : true,
            rawPrice : rawLoaded
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.warn(`An error occured while fetching data - ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your code but still getting wrong results when I print rawLoaded. I'm fetching from url that contains 'p/ajax/file.json'. Is it related to the behavior of ajax somehow?